# SQL Server 2012 Asp .Net . Timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, timeout

The asp .net app (MVC 3, .Net 4) has been in use for over 4 hours.  Last month we upgraded from SQL Server 2005 to 2012 (SP2).  Everything worked as expected.  However, after a month from the upgrade, we had this issue today.

```
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached
```

The system started to work normally after about 20 minutes on its own.  On weekdays, the app receives heavy workload and this never happened.  Today (Sunday), there were hardly 2-3 users online  when this error occurred and persisted for 20 minutes (we log heavily... pretty much everything so we can find out what happened, when it happened and how long the issue persisted).

Scratching my head to find out how the pool got exhausted when there were only a few users online. Never any issues with a large number of concurrent users in the last four years.  Any pointers?

**EDIT**

After searching through this site, I found the following SQL to get open connections:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
       COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections, 
       loginame as LoginName 
FROM sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE dbid > 0 
GROUP BY dbid, loginame
```

We monitored for hours during peak load. Total number of open connections from the app never crosses 10.  However, this statement also shows that there are a large number of connections (around 30) from user sa to master db.  Don't know why?

Comment: Do you have a job on the sql server that refresh the cached query plans? If you don't then I would add a job that runs `sp_updatestats` daily

Comment: looks like you not closing the connection once opened, please DO NOT depend on GC to close your connection objects. Note that you need a Connection.Close in the finally block as well to close the Connection when there are exceptions. Check this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/angelsb/archive/2004/08/25/220333.aspx

Comment: Well, as I said, app has always worked under heavy load.  So connections are properly being closed (otherwise it would crash when load is heavy).  What surprises me that it happened on Sunday afternoon after a period of inactivity when there were only 2-3 concurrent users using the app.

Comment: will try calling sp_updatestats